# How to refactor the following code to use q?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

New to q, I got a sample code as follow, what it does is, get an order, then get the owner of the order, append the name of the owner to the order so that the complete order can be displayed, how to change this to using Q (kriskowal/q)? Thanks,

```
db.get_order(order_id, function(err, order) {
users.get_user(order.user_id, function(err, user) {
    order['$user_name'] = user.name
    console.log(order)
  })
})
```

Comment: Change this to return a promise or change in a way that `db.get_order`  and `users.get_user` return promises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that `get_order` function depends on the `db` object and also `get_user` depends on `user` object. If that is the case, then you need to invoke those methods with [`Q.ninvoke`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qninvokeobject-methodname-args), like this

```
Q.ninvoke(db, "get_order", order_id)
.then(function(order) {
    return Q.ninvoke(user, "get_user", order.user_id);
})
.then(function(user) {
    console.log(user.name);
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, the purpose is not to get the user.name, but to add the user.name to the order, and when reach .then(function(user) { order['$user_name'] = user.name}, problem is, how to access the object order at this point?

Comment: @AngeloC You can retain the retrieved order by storing it in a variable outside the `Q` functions, will that work for you?

Comment: a variable outside of Q functions works, thanks.

Comment: It is also possible to `return [order,Q.ninvoke(user,...)]` and then do `.spread(function(order,user){` instead of the `.then` on user and access it there. You can also always nest but no one likes nesting. On a side note, you should use `nfbind` when possible instead of invoking nfcall each time.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You are correct, if the OP uses it more than once he can `bind` it

Comment: @AngeloC If you are calling `db.get_order`/`user.get_user` often, you need to use `Q.nfbind`. Check that in the API Docs, if you need clarifications, please feel free to comment here :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum nbind works too, following is a rewrite, is it correct? 
  var get_order = Q.nbind(dao.get_order, dao)
  var get_user = Q.nbind(users.get_user, users)

  var order

  get_order(order_id)
    .then(function(order_) {
      order = order_
      return get_user(order.user_id)
    }).done(function(user) {
      order.$user_name = user.name
      console.log(order)
    })

Comment: @AngeloC In all honesty? I'd use Bluebird, it's a much faster library, it promisifies a lot better with `promisifyAll`, it detects unhandled rejections and it manages contexts with `.bind`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum will take a look at Bluebird, reason I choose q is, it is the one use in angularjs, and that's the front end I'm using now, in fact it is angularjs convince me to use Promise:)

Comment: @AngeloC AngularJS does not use Q it uses `$q` which is a really dumbed down version of Q with slightly different semantics. Both Q and Bluebird implement the Promises/A+ specification and all of `$q`s methods. I'm glad you like promises, they really do help.